# Schema graphql error gives 'Cannot return null for non-nullable field Organisation.id' why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I have a graphql schema in Amplify with a simple Model. I get the error "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Organisation.id." when I try to fetch a valid ID, why?

**Model**

```
type Organisation 
  @model
  {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
  }
```

**Query:**

```
const org = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getOrganisationQuery, { id: 'f18881fb-4cf3-42de-84b1-9396f932938d' }));
```

**Error:**
Cannot return null for non-nullable field Organisation.id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!` indicates that the returning value cannot be null for the field

#### Fix 1

remove the exclamation symbol `!` to remove the error

#### Fix 2

make sure the value is present for the field